# How to see timelike excitation has a negative norm from the "old covariant quantization"

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, hilbert-space, constrained-dynamics, unitarity

I have a question in reading Polchinski's string theory vol I p 123, about the "old covariant quantization".

It is said

> ... $\langle 0;k | 0; k' \rangle = ( 2\pi)^D \delta^D (k-k') \tag{4.1.15}$
>   as follows from momentum conservation. The timelike excitation has a negative norm.

How to see "the timelike excitation has a negative norm"? Is Dirac delta function in the RHS of Eq. (4.1.15) either $0$ or $\infty$?

Comment: [Dirac Delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Does that answer your question ? .

Comment: No... I didn't see the negative norm....

Comment: The definition of a time-like excitation, by the way, is to have a negative norm, i.e. $\|\psi\|^2<0$ . I don't exactly see the questionm here .

Comment: Do you mean Polchinski simply state the definition of time-like excitation here? I thought it should have some reasoning behind that..

Comment: Yes.    That's what I mean. I see that @Prahar's answer  is different . , but note, there's an $\eta^{00}=-1$ there, so it's essentially the same thing, .

Comment: My problem is, I should check the sign in Eq. (4.1.13) (it is an excited state!), than (4.1.15) (ground state). $$ \langle e; k| e; k' \rangle = e^{\mu*} e_{\mu}  (2 \pi)^D \delta^D(k-k') =\eta_{\mu\nu} e^{\mu*} e^{\nu} (2 \pi)^D \delta^D(k-k') $$. For $e=(1,0,0,0)$ (time-like), the RHS is negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We note
$$
\left[ \alpha_m^0, \alpha_n^0 \right] = \eta^{00} \delta_{m+n,0} = - \delta_{m,-n}
$$
A timelike excitation is $\alpha_{-n}^0 \left| 0; k \right>$. The norm of this state is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left<0;k'\right| \alpha_{m}^0 \alpha_{-n}^0 \left|0;k\right> &= \left<0;k'\right| \left( \left[ \alpha_{m}^0 , \alpha_{-n}^0 \right] + \alpha_{-n}^0 \alpha_{m}^0 \right) \left|0;k\right> \\
&= - \delta_{m,n} \left<0;k'\right. \left|0;k\right> \\
&= - \delta_{m,n} (2\pi)^D \delta^D( k - k' ) < 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus a timelike excitation has negative norm.

Comment: Do you mean a timelike excitation is that, from $e \cdot \alpha_{-1} = e^{\mu} \cdot \alpha_{-1,\mu} $, we Lorentz transform it into $e^{\mu}  \propto (1,0,0,0)$?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.